# download mp4 from chrome video tag,but get an m4a file

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I have a `video` tag on my website, and the user can download the video by right clicking on the video and saving it.
The video source path has a md5 value as the version to avoid browser cache the video when video changed.
When download the video from Firefox, I get the `mp4` file, while I get `m4a` file from the Chrome browser.

```
<html>
  <video src="http://example.mp4?t=21f60a2c5831b2e892201b2612ccc3dc", type="video/mp4">
</html>
```

When I remove the version from the video source path, the file is downloaded as mp4 on both browsers.

```
<html>
  <video src="http://example.mp4", type="video/mp4">
</html>
```

`ffprobe example.mp4`

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'example.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:09:27.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 55 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1024x768, 28 kb/s, 18.83 fps, 18.83 tbr, 14464 tbn, 37.67 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 23 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```